# Type signature needed for aeson decode?

Tags: haskell, aeson

I'm writing a small program to parse JSON from TCP connections, but I've run into an error:

```
Main.hs:43:22:
    No instance for (FromJSON t0) arising from a use of `decode'
    The type variable `t0' is ambiguous
    Possible fix: add a type signature that fixes these type variable(s)
    Note: there is a potential instance available:
      instance FromJSON LogIn -- Defined at Main.hs:21:10
    In the expression: decode lazyLine
    In a pattern binding: Just login = decode lazyLine
    In the expression:
      do { line <- BS.hGetLine handle;
           let lazyLine = BL.fromChunks ...;
           let Just login = decode lazyLine;
           hPutStrLn handle ".";
           .... }
```

I'm at a loss as to what signature to add to `instance FromJSON LogIn`.

The code is:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveGeneric #-}

module Main(main) where

import Network (listenOn, withSocketsDo, accept, PortID(..), Socket)
import System (getArgs)
import System.IO (hSetBuffering, hPutStrLn, BufferMode(..), Handle)
import Control.Concurrent (forkIO)
import qualified Data.ByteString as BS

import Data.Text
import Data.Aeson
import GHC.Generics
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy as BL

data LogIn = LogIn
  { username :: String
  , password :: String
  } deriving (Show, Generic)

instance FromJSON LogIn

main :: IO ()
main = withSocketsDo $ do
    sock <- listenOn $ PortNumber 3333
    putStrLn $ "Listening on " ++ "3333"
    sockHandler sock


sockHandler :: Socket -> IO ()
sockHandler sock = do
    (handle, _, _) <- accept sock
    hSetBuffering handle NoBuffering
    forkIO $ commandProcessor handle
    sockHandler sock


commandProcessor :: Handle -> IO ()
commandProcessor handle = do
    line <- BS.hGetLine handle
    let lazyLine = BL.fromChunks [line]
    let Just login = decode lazyLine
    hPutStrLn handle "." --(show login)
    commandProcessor handle
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will compile:

```
commandProcessor :: Handle -> IO ()
commandProcessor handle = do
    line <- BS.hGetLine handle
    let lazyLine = BL.fromChunks [line]
    let Just login = decode lazyLine :: Maybe LogIn
    hPutStrLn handle "." --(show login)
    commandProcessor handle
```

Basically, you need to tell aeson's decode what you want to decode the JSON string as.

```
let Just login = decode lazyLine :: Maybe LogIn
```

Comment: Thanks, this fixes it.  Out of curiosity, what is the type of lazyLine?  Declaring it as `BL.ByteString` or `IO BL.ByteString` both fail with errors.

Comment: ```lazyline``` is a lazy bytestring. It's actual type is ```Data.ByteString.Internal.Lazy```. The value constructor is hidden, so you need to use functions like ```fromChunks``` to create a value of the lazy bytestring type. To get into more detail just run a ```:t``` on the ```decode``` function in ```ghci```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get Aeson to generate the instance for you, make sure you turn on the extension DeriveGenerics in your compilation

You need to add annotation to the line

Change

```
let Just login = decode lazyLine
```

to

```
let Just login = decode lazyLine :: Maybe LogIn
```

Otherwise, you can manually write the instance.

You need to supply a typeclass instance for `FromJSON LogIn` with `parseJSON` implemented

Like:

[http://hackage.haskell.org/package/aeson-0.6.1.0/docs/Data-Aeson.html#t:FromJSON](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/aeson-0.6.1.0/docs/Data-Aeson.html#t%3aFromJSON)

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

instance FromJSON Coord where
   parseJSON (Object ob) = LogIn            <$>
                           ob .: "username" <*>
                           ob .: "password"

   parseJSON _          = mzero
```

Comment: I'm trying to get aeson to do the work for me, as per http://dev.stephendiehl.com/hask/#json - see "structured".

Comment: I think the issue is a simple monad problem, as when I cange a few things around, the warnings all become about `Couldn't match expected type "IO BL.ByteString" with actual type "BL.ByteString"`.